# Increase min-height on SE code snippets to prevent scrollbar from blocking code

Tags: support, bug, code-formatting, stack-snippets

When using Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow, anytime there's a one-line code snippet with a horizontal scrollbar, the majority of the code becomes covered.

I am using Chrome v72.0.3626.109.

Looks something like this:

[image: stack exchange scrollbar blocking code]

Can we fix this issue?